# Tag "movement": Should we rename it to "movado"?

Tags: discussion, tags

The question title says it all—shall we rename the tag "movement" to "movado" (which is Esperanto and more specific to the Esperanto movement and distinguishing it from other movements)?

Comment: It's worth considering using Esperanto in *all* tags, not just this one.  But it certainly seems appropriate for this one at least.

Comment: @nathaniel: I am also thinking of "tabelvortoj" instead of "correlatives" since this is the technical term. Otherwise, I am fine with a mixture of English and Esperanto tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it is referring to the Esperanto movement, I would use [movado](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movado).
I am not totally sure we need such a tag, but between [movement](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movement) and [movado](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movado) it is preferable the later. The former is too generic, and it should be replaced by [esperanto-movement](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esperanto-movement); since *esperanto* should not appear on our tags, [movado](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movado) is the only alternative I see.

Answer (score 2):

It seems strange to me that just this one tag should be translated to Esperanto and thus *movado*. I personally think we should only have English tags unless we want to translate every tag and have twice as many tags for every question. Unless I'm missing something, if the tag *movement* is used in the Esperanto StackExchange, it certainly refers to the Esperanto movement. I'm against using the tag *movado*.

Comment: I agree with this. Movado literally just means movement. I think you would use the word movado for example to talk about any sort of movement if you were speaking Esperanto. It's no different from if you were in a green political conference and you said “the movement” without specifying which movement you were talking about - it would be obvious that you are talking about the green movement.

Comment: One point for clarity – in all these cases, we'll want to have "synonym" tags that point to the "root" tag.  So if someone enters "movement" as a tag, it will give them "movado" (or vice versa).  We'll thus be able to ensure that only the preferred tags get used.  The process of determining which ones are "preferred," of course, is the tricky part.

Answer (score 2):

The word *movement* is vague, it can be a physical movement, or any kind of movement. With the word [Movado](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto-movado) it is clear that it is about *the social movement that aims to propagate Esperanto in the whole world*. The "Esperanto-movement" in English can be not understood as "movado", it can be understood as "everything in Esperanto", which is not good as we already have more precise tags for that.

Since the tag is too vague, I suggest that we divide *movement* into at least three tags (examples) :

- *movado*, for questions about organisms and methods to propagate the use of EO
- *culture*, for questions about the Esperanto culture
- *speakers*, for questions about Esperanto speakers (demography, fields of usage etc.)

This way, we will benefit more from the precision given by the tags.