# Tag synonym suggestion: [esperanto-movement] -> [movado]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[movado](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movado) and [esperanto-movement](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esperanto-movement) probably mean the same. As was decided in https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23/1576, [movado](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movado) should be the tag to be used.

I think that therefore, [esperanto-movement](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esperanto-movement) should be made an alias to [movado](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movado).

Comment: will this require that [tag:esperanto-movement] is removed as a tag first?

Comment: No, the destination of a synonym doesn't have to be removed first. But in fact, I'd suggest to [_merge_](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/admin/merge-tags?removetag=esperanto-movement) [tag:esperanto-movement] into [tag:movado]. When doing so, the former can be made a synonym of the latter simply by checking a checkbox, it seems.

Comment: That sounds good to me! and it sounds like it will be a straightforward implementation of the consensus in [Should we rename movement to movado](https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/tag-movement-should-we-rename-it-to-movado?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: OK, I'll do it then. [Preview](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/admin/merge-tags?preview=true&mastertag=movado&removetag=esperanto-movement&ensuresynonym=true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done:

> ## Merge Results
>
> ```
> updating post history, 3 rows affected (pipe delimited)
> updating posts, 3 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
> updating PostTags associations, 3 rows affected
> destroying 'esperanto-movement': [esperanto-movement] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
> total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
> 0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
> 0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
> updating count for master tag, new count: 17
> tag remapping of [movado] and [esperanto-movement] complete!
> remapping 0 synonyms
> 0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
> 0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
> Tag Synonym esperanto-movement -> movado was approved!
> ```